# Can a possessing fiend target the possesed creature with "self" range spell like abilities?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, eberron

Can a possessing fiend target the possesed creature with "self" range spell like abilities?

For example an advanced (4 HD) Quasit is possessing a human peasant.  Could the Quasit use it's `Self Only` `Invisibility` on the possessed character?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Yes**, if the fiend acts as a controller. Eberron Campaign Setting, page 101:

> If the possessed creature fails the Will save against control, the fiend has access to all the creature's senses, abilities, skills, feats, and spell knowledge. The fiend now acts as though it is the creature in all respects, until control is lost or it relinquishes control.

And:

> The fiend retains the victim's type and is affected by spells and effects as if the fiend were the possessed creature.

This is assuming the fiend doesn't lose his own spell-like abilities when he possesses someone. As the rules don't say he loses them, he doesn't.

Comment: Well, the rules don't specifically say he loses his Ex powers even though it stands to reason, right? I agree with your conclusion, but tt's not as simple as "the rules don't say so he doesn't."

Comment: Furthermore, "The fiend now acts as though it is the creature in _all respects_" makes me think that the fiend could even lose all of its original abilities.

Answer (score 2):

Interesting question.  It's obvious that someone possessing someone would lose their Ex abilities, as those are more physical attributes.

But they keep their spellcasting, so I think they would *probably* thus keep their Sp abilities.  In the quasit's case, the invisibility is just a spell-like lumped in with the others, so I would say they definitely get it, and "self" would be their containing body.

But what about Su abilities? I'd tend to rule no, unless it entertained me as the GM.

Comment: "unless it entertained me as the GM." >:-D

Comment: Is the spellcasting part the one quoted by Jonathan Drain? If so, it does not mention the fiend's spellcasting but the possessed creature's one.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry for raising this question from the dead, but I think the existing answer may be wrong, depending on what sources you're using. I don't have *Eberron Campaign Setting*, but the *Fiendish Codex I: Hordes of the Abyss* is pretty clear on this. Before possessing a creature, the fiend must "shuck its physical form and take on an incorporeal one that enables it to possess other creatures." So, a possessing fiend is physically present elsewhere when it is possessing a creature via its incorporeal form.

> A fiend in this incorporeal form . . . has no access to its normal
>   suite of abilities. It . . . lacks its extraordinary, supernatural,
>   and spell-like abilities.

*Fiendish Codex I: Hordes of the Abyss,* Page 22.

So, no spell-like abilities, self-only or otherwise.

Comment: *Fiendish Codex* offers a separate, different set of rules from *Eberron Campaign Setting*. Despite being rules for the same thing, they don't really interact with one another.

Comment: I just got a look at pages 100-102 of the _Eberron Campaign Setting_ and it looks like it is a sub-set of the rules published in the _Fiendish Codex_. That is, it looks like the _Fiendish Codex_ takes the Eberron rules and expands on them. So much of the language is identical. "Shucking?" But you are right that they aren't identical. ECS doesn't seem to discuss the fiend being incorporeal and ethereal at the same time, and leaves out the rule about losing abilities. Unless there's a contradiction, however, it looks like the codex can be used compatibly with Eberron.